# Ubuntu 12.10 After installation (D drive and E drive in Windows System) are missing!

Tags: installation, 12.10, partitioning

After Installing Ubuntu 12.10 with Installation option "Replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu" I can't see any drive[ D: and E: ] mounted in Ubuntu. They are not even under /mnt/ location.  What the hell had happened ?
When I looked under /dev location. I found 2 files:
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3

/dev/sda2 was appearing to be 150 GB in size. That equals to my entire harddisk. I'm gettin' mad. LOL

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I guess that you had with Windows 8 a C: disk with the system and D:-E: with data. If you did a "Replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu" you formatted all the disk (all the partitions with NTFS format) and you installed Ubuntu over. That's why I think you have a 150GB partition now.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your replying.
According to that option only C: should be formatted. D: and E: are already separate. Why they get involved into this?
Why Ubuntu didn't give any warning in such case before proceeding?

Comment: Now what I'm supposed to do ?

Comment: With Windows, had you 3 hard drives or only one with 3 partitions?

Comment: one hard drive into 3 partition. I'm worried about my data stored in D: drive. I need to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

When you are formatting you are not actually destroying data so there are several procedures to recover it. You should ask google in order to find somo easy way... Good Luck